# jstack throws exception interrogating a core

Tags: java, jstack

When I use jstack to interrogate a core dump file I get this exception. I've tried using sudo but still the same.

Thanks for any help.

```
Attaching to remote server core.2941, please wait...
Error attaching to remote server: java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid authority: //core.2941/SARemoteDebugger

sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid authority: //core.2941/SARemoteDebugger
at sun.jvm.hotspot.RMIHelper.lookup(RMIHelper.java:115)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.connectRemoteDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:517)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:374)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:183)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:196)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid authority: //core.2941/SARemoteDebugger
at java.rmi.Naming.intParseURL(Naming.java:330)
at java.rmi.Naming.parseURL(Naming.java:237)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:96)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.RMIHelper.lookup(RMIHelper.java:113)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked out what the problem was.

When you connect to a core dump you have to pass in the java executable as well as the core dump file.

So rather than `jstack core` you need to use `jstack /usr/bin/java core`.

(You can even load the core file into visualvm)